# Simple WPF Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, model, treeview

I'm learning WPF, and I'm stuck with Data Bindings. I have a TreeView, which `ItemSource` is set to a `ObserveableCollection<UIBrowserItem>`.

My Binding looks like:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

And my `UIBrowserItem` is very basic:

```
public class UIBrowserItem 
{
    public string Title = "Test";
}
```

But the Items in the TreeView won't have a header set ..

If you need further information, tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only bind to public **properties**, you have a public field. Your code should be:

```
public class UIBrowserItem 
{
    private String title = "Test";
    public string Title
    {
       get { return title; }
       set { title = value; }
}
```

If the title can change at run time, you also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know it has to be that way :)